# visual studio project deployment file confusion?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, deployment

I have gone through all the steps to deploy an XNA VS2008 project and created an installer. I built the project and now have a release file with 3 folders containing dependencies in .msi format, a steup.exe and a solutionName.msi

But which file is the right one? setup.exe doesn't seem to work outside of the folder. Am I meant to send people the whole zipped folder? or just the .msi? Will they have to separately install all the .msi dependencies or will setup.exe do that for them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setup.exe` is meant to check the dependencies, and run the proper msi files based on what is needed.

You could ZIP the folder all up into a self-extracting EXE which unzips to a temp dir and then runs the setup.exe, as one way to package everything together for installation.